# How can I pass variable to ansible playbook from a file (ini file)?

Tags: ansible, parameter-passing

```
vars:
    client_id: “{{client_id}}”
    client_secret: “{{client_secret}}”
```

I want to transmit client_id and client_secret vars from ini file to this Ansible playbook.

How can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

See [ini - read data from a ini file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/ini.html#ini-read-data-from-a-ini-file)

```
vars:
    client_id: “{{ lookup('ini', 'client_id file=file.ini') }}”
    client_secret: “{{ lookup('ini', 'client_secret file=file.ini') }}”
```